# ViewPager Fragments taking time to load

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a custom ViewPager in which I have 4 fragments, each fragment has different listviews, and its on the start screen of the application. The listview's are taking time to load as soon as the application starts. I'm not pulling any data into the listview, its just the implementation. Implemented OnPageChangeListener to change the listview as I swipe through the fragments

Why does this happen?

Comment: could you write your code?

Comment: @Adri Added my code, I think it is also having some logical error, I'm unable to get that, the behavior OnItemClickListener is weird.

Comment: For all the cases, I'm getting the position as 1

Answer (score 0):

changed the implementation, instead of fragments I used PagerAdapter.